# In my Django-project how can I dynamically append a script which is located in the static folder to the head-section?

Tags: javascript, django, dynamic, appendchild, static-files

In my Django-project I would like to dynamically append a `script`-tag to the `head`-section. The script I want to append is located in `static`-folder.
The problem is that I don't know how to reference the `static`-folder in javascript, or if that is even pssible.

This is (a part of) my Javascript:

```
jQuery( window ).on( "load", () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "{% static 'js/myScript.js' %}";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

myScript.js could look like this:

```
console.log("This is myScript")
```

Of course this does not work. In the console I get:

GET [http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'js/myScript.js'%20%%7D](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20%27js/myScript.js%27%20%%7D) net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

Is there a way to reference the `static`-folder inside a javascript?

Comment: You could embed this snippet of JS in your template, then the static tag would be parsed as intended. Where does your JS file come form? If it in static as well you could probably use a relative path, so simpoy script src="myScript.js" ?

Comment: I cannot get the suggestion, to put the file in the same folder and use a relative path, to work. Putting it in the template will probably work, but it is not my preffered solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing:

```
script.src = "{% static 'js/myScript.js' %}";
```

into:

```
script.src = "/static/js/myScript.js";
```

As simple as that!